# Can't open properly a SSIS package based job from SSMS in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-job

I need to understand what a certain job in SQL Server 2012 does. It's a job someone created and left the company before I started to work here, and nobody on my team knows what this job does also.

The job isn't SQL command based but SSIS Package (which I'm not familiar with), the package points to a Maintenance Plan with the same name as the job. As I read on the internet I connected via Integration Services type, then Stored Packages -> MSDB -> Maintenance Plans, right click on the Maintenance Plan and exported it to a .dtsx file.

I opened it in Visual Studio 2010 Shell, but I can't edit anything because of this error:

> The task with the name "" and the creation name "" is not registered for use on this computer.

I also don't have a Solution Explorer for that package, and the icons of the tasks seem a bit faded compared to tasks icons of a new project if I create one.

Maybe the dated version of the VS can be the problem? Perhaps there is other way to see what this job does?

I never worked with SSIS before so maybe I'm missing something very basic but I've been on the Internet for days already and can't find any solution.

Please help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would, personally, suggest installed VS 2017 and SSDT, or VS 2019 with the SSIS Extension. Then create an SSIS project in which ever you installed, and then add the `.dtsx` package to your new project.

Comment: Otherwise, if you have a package that no one knows what it does, it can't be *that* important and should be disabled... You should have code you have no idea about running on your production environment. Though if things start failing, then this shows a severe flaw in the Business Process.

Answer (score 0):

By way of background, until Visual Studio 2019, VS, by itself, couldn't open an SSIS package.

Prior to VS 2010, you needed to use a different product, called Business Intelligence Design Studio (BIDS), which was based on VS, but was built for SQL Server functionality. With the release of SQL Server 2012, Microsoft created SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) as a plugin for VS that required a separate installation. Until SSDT(VS) 2017, you needed to have stand-alone versions of BIDS or SSDT for each version of SSIS you were working with in your environment. The 2017 version, though, is backward compatible to SQL Server 2012, and forward compatible (!) to SQL Server 2019. Visual Studio 2019 has SQL Server Data Tools sort of built in, but you need to add extensions through the extension manager for SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), Analysis Services (SSAS), and/or Reporting Services (SSRS).

That's kind of a lot to take in, and is sort of irrelevant to you, but it forms the context for Larnu's comments. Rather than messing around with antique versions of Visual Studio, you should just install either VS2017 and also SSDT, or VS2019 with the SSIS extension. Both are in current widespread use, so support is easy to find, and either will allow you to work with the 2012 package you're trying to open up.

Once you have the software installed, you should be able to create a "dummy" integration services solution that you can use to open random packages. I keep one around called `MiscSolution`. Right click on the solution name, select Add -> Existing Item. Then find your .dtsx package and import it. (Or right click SSIS Packages -> Add Existing Package. I always do it at the Solution level because that interface allows you to select multiple packages.)

Note that when you do this, you're making a new copy of the package in your local solution directory. You are NOT working on the copy of the package that sits in the folder where you picked it up. This matters if you're going to be making any changes, since it will need to be redeployed. It also matters if you accidentally hose up the package, because you've done no harm as long as you just delete that copy.

Once the package imports, which might take a minute or so depending on how complex it is, you should be able to open it up and see what's going on.